# Finding a Jordan base

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}: \mathbb{R}\underset{\leqslant 3}{[x]}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\underset{\leqslant 3}{[x]}$ be the derivative operator. I am trying to find a base $B\subset V$ and a Jordan block matrix $J$ so that $\left [ \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \right ]_{B}=J$.

I chose the standard base $E=(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ and found $\left [ \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \right ]_{E}$ = $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &3 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0 
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. I found that the minimal polynomial is $x^4$ and therefore the suitable Jordan matrix is: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0 
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.
I couldn't find a Jordan form base for it,
how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix as almost the right form, you are just off by multiplicative coefficients. By linearity, if you divide by two your third vector the image will also be divided by 2, right? So you obtain the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0& 0 & 0 & 6\\ 0& 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ in the base $(1,x,\frac{x^2}{2},x^3)$. Apply the same argument to correct the $6$ in the third row!

Comment: Ok , I understand! Thank you very much!